# Vertical and horizontal alignment of <li> within a fluid navbar in a table cell

Tags: html, css, navigation, vertical-alignment

#### Objective

What I am trying to achieve is have my `<nav>`s links be centered (vertically and horizontally), my `<nav>`s links have a defined liquid width that can contain the text, and my `<nav>` element be liquid and expand to fit the needs of the `<li>`s.

#### Attempts

I vertically centered my `<li>`s within my fixed navbar, but now the text is overflowing from the cells and I want the cells to expand to fit the text within.

## HTML

```
<nav id="page-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#connect">Connect</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://example.org/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
    </li>    
  </ul>
</nav>
```

### CSS

```css
#page-nav {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: right;
}

#page-nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  display: table;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 125%;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#page-nav li {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0% 2%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#page-nav a {
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

#page-nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant, and I noticed I made some small errors to the code 'width: 20%;' shouldn't have been in the #page-nav, sorry this was my experiment code. Sorry for not getting back sooner!

Comment: I'd also like to apologize for the lack of certain details and I'd like to again thank you for your time and help!

Comment: I've heard of it through JS, but I've never done it

Comment: You should try to avoid using IDs for styling because of the selector specificity wars you create. IDs are great for selecting things with JS and jQuery though.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your `#pagenav` CSS:

```
#page-nav {
  text-align: center !important;
  height: 100%;
  float: none;
}
```

If i am understanding what you want that should center it all on itself in a row.

Comment: I tried it and the unordered list was moved to line below and the list items were spread between the whole line, thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your main concern is to center vertically and horizontally. I added some color for demo purposes on this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejBso) which produced this

[image]

To center your text vertically just set the `line-height` of your `<li>` equal to the height of your `<ul>` and make the containing `<nav>` to have a `height: auto;`. But do not use a table for this.

Then center your text horizontally give your `<li>` a rule of `text-align: center;` to center it.

Here is an example, modify according to your own needs

```
#page-nav {
  /* you can set the height of container to auto */
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: right;
}

#page-nav ul {
  /* modify to your height */
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 125%;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#page-nav li {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0% 2%;
  /* use inline-block instead */
  display: inline-block;
  /* set line height equal to its parents height */
  line-height: 2em;
  /* Center your text inside the li */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @Christina I think you meant to leave those as comments to the question. Not my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your time and response, sorry I didn't reply sooner. I'm trying it at the moment and will let you know how things workout! Thanks again!